# Pass parameters to MVC controller by Response.Redirect in WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, response.redirect

I have a webform (.aspx page) with `ReportViewer` that uses server report and a button that redirects to `MVC` controller action - `Index`.
I would like to pass server report parameters to my controller action. Is it possible?

So, I get the params:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ReportParameterInfo> param = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetParameters().ToList();
    string month = param.Where(p => p.Name == "month").FirstOrDefault().Values.FirstOrDefault();
    string year = param.Where(p => p.Name == "year").FirstOrDefault().Values.FirstOrDefault();

    Response.Redirect("/Report/");
}
```

My index `ActionResult` looks as usually:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    { 
            ....
           return View(); //returns .cshtml view
    }
```

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Looks like your action does not expect any parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could pass it via query string, and use the model binder from MVC.

Use `Response.Redirect("/Report/?Year=2014&Month=2");` from your web forms app. Then add parameters to your action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int year, int month)
{ 
    // year and month will be populated with the query string values
    return View(); //returns .cshtml view
}
```